# Assign direction based on values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this example dataset (`df`):

```
structure(list(sensor = c(12, 12, 12, 8, 12, 12, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

[image]

I'd like to make a new column called `direction` where any time `sensor` changes from 12 to 8, I'd input `out` in the same row as `12` and any time `sensor` changes from 8 to 12, I'd input `in` in the same row as `12`.

My desired dataset would look like this:

[image]

I'm thinking of using `dplyr` mutate function. But can't quite figure out the best way to do so:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(direction = if_else(...))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case_when` will also do the job

```
df %>%
    mutate(direction = case_when(lag(sensor)==12 & sensor==8 ~ 'out',
                                 lag(sensor)==8 & sensor==12 ~ 'in'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(df1, {
    temp = c(diff(sensor), 0)
    ifelse(temp == -4, "out", ifelse(temp == 4, "in", NA))
})
#[1] NA    NA    "out" "in"  NA    "out" NA
```